# Div not appearing inside the popup

Tags: jquery, html, popup, append

I am trying to render a div inside a new popup box. I am using :

```
var popup = window.open('about:blank','instructions','width=300,height=200');
popup.onload = function() {
    jQuery(popup.document.body).append(".chart");
}
```

to append the div called chart to the popup. This just creates a blank popup window and the div is still rendered on the same html page. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/remecsce/). I dont understand what is going wrong here. According to my understanding , it should have opened the div as the new popup. Also, this div is being created dynamically.

UPDATE: I also tried to append the div like this:

```
    var popup = window.open('about:blank','instructions','width=300,height=200');
    popup.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("popup").appendChild(".chart");
}
```

Even this didn't work. If there is any other approach to render a div inside a new popup, please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 var html = $('.chart').html();
  var popup = window.open('about:blank','instructions','width=300,height=200');
  popup.onload = function() {
    jQuery(popup.document.body).append(html);
  }
```

Comment: Try jQuery(popup.document.body).html(html); (.html instead of .append)

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
var html = $('.chart').html();
 var popup = window.open('','instructions','width=300,height=200');
 $(popup.document.body).html(html);
```

But before that, please note that in your html, div with selector class 'chart' is empty. I think you need to close that div at the end of that table.

UPDATE

For CSS

Put the css inline like below

```
<style id="chartcss">
    .chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

And update your code to below :

```
var html = $('.chart').clone();
 var popup = window.open('','instructions','width=300,height=200');
 $(popup.document.body).append(html).append($('#chartcss'));
```

Comment: No its actually being generated by d3 code that I have written in javascript. It renders a bar chart in the location where the div chart is put.

Comment: Your code does put the div values in the popup but the css gets messed up. Somehow its not applying the css. http://jsfiddle.net/remecsce/3/

Answer (score 0):

try changing the append to:

```
jQuery(popup.document.body).append($(".chart").html());
```

you are using the string value ".char" instead of a reference to the div **$(**".char"**)**

**UPDATE**: Lets try old school.

```
popup.document.write($(".chart").html());
```

**HINT**: Actually, because the popup is open with **about:blank** the onload event its never invoked, I guess this is because there is no content to load.

I removed the enclose function and it worked, probably both of the solutions mentioned above work as well.

A fork of your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c9f96h0z/)

Comment: still renders the div on the same page and a blank popup window

Comment: still doesn't work for my fiddle. I have attached my fiddle above.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the call to window.open in your fiddle.

Comment: It still opens just a blank pop up

Answer (score -1):

You are opening a new browser window with the window.open() method, you cannot modify it with javascript on the former page, I would suggest using Twitter Bootstrap's "Modal" javascript and html functionality, so you don't actually open another window, just a div within the current page that looks like one

here is a link: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I need to render the div as a popup